What exactly constitutes as a proof for a proposition?
It seems that in philosophy, a proof of a (non mathematical) proposition often involves ruling out all potential alternative imagined scenarios, no matter how implausible.
For example, many philosophers have stated that one cannot prove that solipsism isn’t true (i.e. that our mind is the only one that exists). One can certainly imagine a universe where we are the only mind and everyone else is simply a construct of our mind and nothing else (I.e. no external world).
But why does a “proof” have to involve ruling out imagined scenarios and who decided this to be the case? Clearly , just because one can imagine something, does not imply that it exists.
To put it another way, what “proof” is there that one must rule out all alternative imagined scenarios in order to “prove” a proposition?

The premise is wrong, making the whole question useless. There are different forms of proof in logic, science and rhetorics, and elimination of alternatives is the least useful one .

In general it would be preferable to start this kind of question with a reference work of philosophy, and then ask something that remains unclear in the source.

@tkruse Can you show me an example of a proof of a statement like “tkruse is a human being” without ruling out all alternative scenarios?

@Syed Ruling out alternatives as a form of "proof" is liable to the Holmesian fallacy.

@user80226 your attached link is proving my point. If you read it, it says that it’s a fallacy because one often can’t actually rule out all alternatives. In other words, your link agrees that ruling out all alternatives would constitute as proof: it’s just that it often, if not always, can’t be done

People prove they are humans using Captchas on the internet: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA

@tkruse solving a CAPTCHA doesn’t prove that you’re a human from a philosophical standpoint. In fact, some bots can solve CAPTCHAs. Once again, when pinned down, the usual objections to my questions almost always are borne out of ignorance.

If you bleed red and can use language well, I surmise that you are human. Now this won't hurt a bit...

I think it was Aristotle who wrote about the truthfulness of Captchas. Or maybe I wasn't serious because the whole question did not make sense. Take your pick

Frame challenge.
The scientific point of view is that outside limited universes like mathematics, things are never proved, they are just accepted as a better working theory than anything else that has been found to date.
That may be the difference between science and philosophy: science is willing to accept progress toward truth, with error and correction along the way, whereas philosophy believes perfection is attainable.
And as I have grumbled elsewhere, one form of bad philosophy is forgetting that you decided to work in a limited universe to make a proof possible.
